# Faker Gem to Specific Values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, faker

Assuming I have a simple factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :state do
    name Faker::Address.state_abbr    
  end
end
```

For instance, most of our unit tests used are 'ok' with having a random `state_abbr` for instance.

However, I have some integration tests that rely on dropdowns (To pick a state in a form) and since I don't know what is going to be generated I can't specifically pick it.

Since doing something like this:
`@state = FactoryGirl.create(:state, state_abbr: 'WA')`

Doesn't seem to work in my Capybara integration specs. Is there some way to override what faker is generating?

(Since I get an error similar such as:

Failure/Error: @state = FactoryGirl.create(:state, state_abbr: 'WA')
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `state_abbr=' for #

with the "name: "XX" changing abbreviations.

For reference I can't really just go and change the factory, as many other unit tests are relying on it, this is for New integration tests.

Comment: What do you mean `@state = FactoryGirl.create(:state, state_abbr: 'WA')` isn't working? Of course not, you're setting `name` in your factory.

Comment: :facepalm: moment for sure by me ha!

Comment: No worries man, happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because in your state factory the field is `name` not `state_abbr`

```
@state = FactoryGirl.create(:state, name: 'WA')
```

Comment: :slaps forhead: wow lol. At least I know it's doable! ha. Factories being completely new to me doesn't help haha. I was using a reference from a user factory to do this, and for some reason the model "name" in this case was the same as what is was equaling on the right.